# Literally canvas on mobiles in landscape mode

Tags: html, css, canvas

Is there a built in solution to get round the `min-height: 400px;` that is applied to literally canvas? - not override it but reduce margins/padding within the interface or swap out the menu buttons for smaller one?  Literally canvas seems to not be able to display on most mobiles in landscape - which is a shame because it looks like its about 40-60px off.

Comment: Can you post a code example to demonstrate the issue you are describing.

Comment: @csmckelvey I did not post any CSS or html because the question was primarily a brainstorming question directed at those who have used Literally Canvas - not necessarily looking for 'code' but an answer as to whether the api has a reduced icon set or separate stylesheet for small screens.  I'm using all the defaults in Literally Canvas so it's just a div with `min-height:400px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally canvas uses a class called .literally on its wrapper div so to minimise the interface (all the buttons etc.) a little more when fullscreen for a mobile's landscape screen I did this:

```
:fullscreen .literally *
{
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    margin-bottom: 1px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    line-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Then for the literally canvas div, I reset the min-height as follows:

```
:fullscreen .literally
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 325 !important; /* reduce literally canvas's min-height */
}
```

This reduces the app more than enough to fit.